# Storing image in Database and retrieving it

Tags: php, html

In php if i have a image uploading option in my form then how can i store that image in Database and as per need how can i retrieve it.I have a form with some fields like Name Age Email etc. and one field is about user's image. So tell me how can i upload a picture and store it and retrieve it again in next page.Can i use just simple input tag in HTML code and declare type as file.

```
<body>
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</body>
```

Comment: I would store the path to the image in the database and not the image itself

Comment: Upload it physically on the hard drive and just insert the path/file.jpg in the db

Comment: Why do you want to store it in DB? Why not on FTP?

Comment: upload the file as normal save a reference to the file location in the database

Comment: On SO are about > 5 questions exactly like this...

Comment: Have a look here and then store the image filename/path in the database.  http://www.infotuts.com/image-file-upload-script-php/

Comment: @Sunil Pachlanga Sunil Pachlanga ???

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to use `<form>`.
2. You have to have enctype attribute there in form.

**Example:**

```
<body>
  <form action='index.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpeg" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit Form" />
  </form>
</body>
```

You have to use $_FILES, then upload it with `move_uploaded_file()`.

[Use this tutorial](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx)

PS: Why do you want to upload it to DB? Why not saving to the server?

You should store it on the server, and write path to DB:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 'some_folder_with_images/'.$_FILES['img']['name']);
}
```

And then this will be your query (example), and of course you should escape file name, or just generate your own file name of stored file on the server:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO images (image_path) 
          VALUES ('".$_FILES['img']['name']."')";
```

PS: use `mysqli_*`, `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Sunil, if you want to insert/upload image into database than you have to use blob field type to insert image.

I feel you should go through with this http://vikasmahajan.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/inserting-and-displaying-images-in-mysql-using-php/ article to add and retrieve image/picture to db.